# why gdb only show 32 bit address on 64 bit machine?

Tags: gdb, 64-bit

Here's screenshot of my problem (see command x/1wt &f)
[image]

I want to examine the address of variable f. As my computer is 64 bit, I expect it to be a 64-long binary number. however it only displays 32 bit. can any one explain why this happens?

Comment: The process is probably 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `x/1wt &f`, this says, show one 32-bit word, as binary at the address of variable `f`.  The `&` does mean address of.

If you want to see the address itself, then you want the `print` command, which can be shortened to `p`, so `p/x &f` will print the address of variable `f` as hexadecimal.

The `gdb` help system is pretty good, so `help x` and `help p` will give a full description of the flags available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a mistake. & does not mean address here.